# How to create a ListPlot containing two lists?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I'm trying to plot a set of points where one list corresponds to the `X` values another list corresponds to the `Y` values.
I have tried

```
ListPlot[{X,Y}]
```

with no luck...

Comment: `ListPlot[Transpose@{X,Y}]`

Comment: `ListPlot@Thread[{X, Y}]` is *cool* too :D

Comment: But `Transpose` is way faster :(

Comment: @Öskå FYI: `Transpose` is only faster on packed data, at least in version 7.